# Mongoose dropDatabase doesn't call callback function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

There is some problem with dropDatabase callback, it never calls. Here is my code:

```
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState); // prints 1 (connected)
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
db.dropDatabase(function() {
    console.log("dropped (callback)"); // never calls
});
console.log("dropped"); // prints "dropped"
```

In the Mongod log I see:

```
Sat Oct  5 19:26:44.074 [conn278] dropDatabase test starting
Sat Oct  5 19:26:44.088 [conn278] removeJournalFiles
Sat Oct  5 19:26:44.104 [conn276] end connection 127.0.0.1:57207 (4 connections now open)
Sat Oct  5 19:26:44.105 [conn278] dropDatabase test finished
```

mongoose version is `1.3.11`.

Comment: 1.3.11 is probably the MongoDB driver version, Mongoose is at 3.6.20. `dropDatabase` works as expected for me (using driver 1.3.19).

Comment: Are you closing your connection before your callback has a chance to get called?

Comment: @JohnnyHK probably yes. I removed forgotten connection from another file, and callback called again. Thank your for help!